# how to check a key value is string or Integer (ios,Android) both

Tags: android, ios, swift

Hello every one am newly in app development ,I have a json data and there is key (order_id) some time order_id value is return ("order_id": "188") but some time return Integer like that  ("order_id": 188) .is there any way to find that is return string or Integer in ios(swift) and android both thanks

here is example of json response

```
"orders": [
        {
            "order_id": "188",
            "invoice_id": "OR180413-188",
            "order_status": "1"
        }
        ]
```

And some time like that

```
"orders": [
            {
                "order_id": 188,
                "invoice_id": "OR180413-188",
                "order_status": "1"
            }
            ]
```

Comment: as per you response it seems to be in string format only. you can convert this string to Int.

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore some time it will be Integer like that ( "order_id": 188)

Comment: Sounds like you should be more consistent in how your JSON data is returned. You should not have different formats in your data. Wherever this JSON data is created, make sure you only create your order_id as a String value.

Comment: parse as Any and convert it into string

Comment: iOS and Android are two completely different platforms and – unless you are programming in Swift on Android devices – there is no common answer. I strongly suggest to make this 2 separate questions, otherwise it might be considered “too broad.”

Comment: @GorakhYadav Included the Answer, lemme know if it worked for you or not.?

Comment: thanks @AbhirajsinhThakore for help its not work for me

Comment: @GorakhYadav Can you please explain what issue you are facing , why its not helping you so that i can make a new one for you

Answer (score 0):

### Swift

You can use like:

```
 let str = "188" // Your response string or Int here
    var sInt:Int = Int()

    // Check if 's' is a String

    if str is String {
        print("Yes, it's a String")
        sInt = Int(str)!
        print(sInt)
    }else{
        print("Not a string")
    }
```

**Another Way is:**

You can forcefully convert it to string and then Int for safer side

```
let str = "\(strResponse)" // Your String here
let strToInt = Int(str)
```

Comment: I think Converting Forcefully it to string and Then back to Int will work for You.

Answer (score 0):

Android :

```
Object order_id = jsonarray.getJsonObject(0).getInt("order_id");
Object invoice_id = jsonarray.getJsonObject(0).getString("invoice_id");
Object order_status= jsonarray.getJsonObject(0).getInt("order_status");

if(order_id instanceOf String)
    // do what you want
.....
```

May be this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You could decode it as string even when it's an integer with **Swift 4**:

```
struct Order: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case orderId = "order_id"
    }

    let orderId: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let orderId = try container?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .orderId) {
            self.orderId = orderId
        } else if let orderId = try container?.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .orderId)  {
            self.orderId = String(orderId)
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(
                codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                debugDescription: "Couldn't decode orderId"
            ))
        }
    }
}
```